# Php Array element as Object key iterator

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object, key

I have an array with following elements:
`$arr = ['N','P','K','Ca','Mg','S', 'Zn', 'B','Cu','Fe','Mn','Mo'];`

How can I use the array element as an object key in order to get only the values for the specific key:

```
object(stdClass)[727]
      public 'id' => int 1
      public 'name' => string 'John Doe' (length=8)
      public 'fname' => string 'HOUSE' (length=5)
      public 'bname' => string 'BLOCK 9' (length=7)
      public 'hectares' => float 7.2
      public 'cname' => string 'Vitis vinifera' (length=14)
      public 'delivery' => string '2210.0000' (length=9)
      public 'view_application' => int 1
      public 'view_schedule' => int 1
      public 'edit_schedule' => int 0
      public 'updated_at' => string '2020-07-17 20:03:51' (length=19)
      public 'N' => string '4.9000' (length=6)
      public 'P' => string '1.1000' (length=6)
      public 'K' => string '6.0000' (length=6)
      public 'Ca' => string '5.4000' (length=6)
      public 'Mg' => string '0.8000' (length=6)
      public 'S' => string '0.0000' (length=6)
      public 'Zn' => string '0.0210' (length=6)
      public 'B' => string '0.0071' (length=6)
      public 'Cu' => string '0.0280' (length=6)
      public 'Fe' => string '0.0420' (length=6)
      public 'Mn' => string '0.0220' (length=6)
      public 'Mo' => string '0.0000' (length=6)
```

I tried using this:

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++)
   $object->$arr[$i];
@endfor
```

But this gave an error `Array to string conversion`

The alternative is to convert the object to array using `$newarr = (array) $object;`
Then iterating using `$object[''.arr[$i].''];`

But this won't work in my case as I have done most of my project using the object.
Is there a way to use an array element as object key without converting the object to an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make it recognise that the second part is the name of an element, so encapsulate it in braces...

```
$object->{$arr[$i]};
```

Comment: Great! That's it.  Thank you. Did you find a duplicate as I did not?  If you don't find a duplicate within 24 hrs I will mark your answer as the solution.  What does the curly braces do with the key?  I know that is the mark of initialising an object.

Comment: I cannot wait any longer.  Marked.